# How to remove row in 2d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, delete-row

How to remove row in two dimensional array in JavaScript with row number. If I want to delete all elements in row number 4 then how can do it??

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's an example of how to remove a row by using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var array = [];

var count = 0;
for (var row=0; row<4; row++) {
    array[row] = [];
    for (var col=0; col<5; col++) {
      array[row][col] = count++;
    }
}

console.log(array);

   [ [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4  ],
     [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9  ],
     [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ],
     [ 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ] ]


function deleteRow(arr, row) {
   arr = arr.slice(0); // make copy
   arr.splice(row - 1, 1);
   return arr;
}

console.log(deleteRow(array, 4));

[ [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4  ],
  [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9  ],
  [ 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ] ]
```

Comment: This code is not deleting the correct row.its deleting some other else in my case.

Comment: @RajaniRampelli what does your array data look like?

Comment: My array is of type string.

Comment: It only can delete the last row i think. Middle rows are not deleting properly.

Comment: This will not work and you can use splice even in multidimensional array. `array.splice(indexOfArr,1)`

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you have an array 'arr' then you can remove full row by `arr.splice(3,1)`;

Comment: What is 3.In this case??  row -1??

Comment: It is specific to your question, you mentioned 4th element. So if you want to removed nth row then use arr.splice(n-1,1). Here first parameter is the index of the row, and second parameter for how many element you want to remove. In your case of 2D array, it means how many rows you want to delete.

Comment: what are you passing as first parameter?

Comment: This code deleting the last row. If array have 4th row is getting deleted. If 6rows array have. 6th row will get deleted.

Comment: In your case, row will be having total number of rows, then only your last row would be deleted. See this link. http://jsbin.com/qopizojide/1/

Comment: Choose it as best answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 4):

I realize this question is old, but it is one of the first results when searching for how to remove from a 2d (multidimensional) array in JS.

Here is what I used to delete the inner array based on a key of the inner array. It should continue to work if there were multiple instances of the same key. In this example, I am searching for, and removing the array with the key of 18.

Sorry about the formatting - it gets the point across.

```js
var items = [
  ["19", 1],
  ["18", 2],
  ["20", 3]
];

//console.log(items);
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = items;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i][0] == "18") {
    items.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

//console.log(items);
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = items;
```

```html
<p>Before</p>
<div id='a'></div>

<p>After</p>
<div id='b'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was brilliant.

Comment: Thanks, this was the only one that worked for my 2d array

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `splice(4, 1)` method, when 4 is row number and 1 is number of rows to remove -

```
twoDimensionalArray.splice(4, 1); // remove 4th row
```

Also `shift()` and `pop()` are very handy methods which remove first and last rows accordingly -

```
twoDimensionalArray.shift(); // to remove first row
twoDimensionalArray.pop(); // to remove last row
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a visual example of a bidimensional array with row deletion button (delete by ID) + jQuery preview of the table.
I hope it can be usefull!

`JS DELETE ROW from Bidimensional ARRAY + Show on jQuery Cart Table` https://jsbin.com/xeqixi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -1):

delete array[index];
array.length--;

In your case give index as 4 and execute the above statement and you need to manually reduce the length of array.

Comment: Manually adjusting the `length` property is a red flag. Your code will leave an empty item in index 4, and you will lose the last item in the array.